# Chart from a csv file using pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts

I have data in the form of dictionaries in the list, generated from the csv file.

```
df = [{'Line Number': 11, 'Report Hour': 6, 'Kits Completed': 34}, {'Line Number': 11, 'Report Hour': 7, 'Kits Completed': 55}, {'Line Number': 12, 'Report Hour': 6, 'Kits Completed': 67}, {'Line Number': 12, 'Report Hour': 7, 'Kits Completed': 56}, {'Line Number': 14, 'Report Hour': 6, 'Kits Completed': 0}, {'Line Number': 14, 'Report Hour': 7, 'Kits Completed': 0}, {'Line Number': 15, 'Report Hour': 6, 'Kits Completed': 123}, {'Line Number': 15, 'Report Hour': 7, 'Kits Completed': 97
```

To achieve the result shown above, I used the code:

```
df = df.to_dict('records')
```

What interests me is getting the result: line 11: did x (axis) o'clock, y (axis) of boxes. line 15: did x (axis) o'clock, y (axis) of boxes.

Then on the same graph, put the results for lines 14, 15, and so on. The effect should look something similar to the one below:

[chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1yoS.png)

*I would be grateful for help :)*

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to create a chart without modifying the csv file. It contains many columns, and I'm only interested in these three. That's why I created this dictionary in the list but I don't know if it's a good idea because I'm stuck; (

Comment: For line 11 at hour=6, the data shows 34 completed, graph shows 65.  Something amiss ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't have converted the pandas dataframe to a dictionary, plotting is much easier with pandas:

```
df = [{'Line Number': 11, 'Report Hour': 6, 'Kits Completed': 34}, {'Line Number': 11, 'Report Hour': 7, 'Kits Completed': 55}, {'Line Number': 12, 'Report Hour': 6, 'Kits Completed': 67}, {'Line Number': 12, 'Report Hour': 7, 'Kits Completed': 56}, {'Line Number': 14, 'Report Hour': 6, 'Kits Completed': 0}, {'Line Number': 14, 'Report Hour': 7, 'Kits Completed': 0}, {'Line Number': 15, 'Report Hour': 6, 'Kits Completed': 123}, {'Line Number': 15, 'Report Hour': 7, 'Kits Completed': 97}]
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

table = df.pivot(index='Report Hour', columns='Line Number', values = 'Kits Completed')
table.plot.bar()
```

Gives:

[image: bar plot]